# Why is there no git-remote-hg package in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, git, official-repositories, mercurial

[Ubuntu package search for `git-remote-hg`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=git-remote-hg) shows:

> ### Package git-remote-hg
>
> - [xenial (16.04LTS)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/git-remote-hg) (vcs): bidirectional bridge between Git and Mercurial **[universe]**
>     0.3-1: all
> - [disco (19.04)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/git-remote-hg) (vcs): bidirectional bridge between Git and Mercurial **[universe]**
>     1.0.0~ds-1: all
> - [eoan](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/git-remote-hg) (vcs): bidirectional bridge between Git and Mercurial **[universe]**
>     1.0.0~ds-1: all

Why is there no `git-remote-hg` package for bionic ([18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04)), when it was present in both the earlier [16.04](/questions/tagged/16.04) and the later [19.04](/questions/tagged/19.04)?  What is the simplest alternative way to install it for 18.04?

Comment: Get it from the source: https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-hg

Comment: It's a community package (universe), so no-one stepped up to do the work.  Despite what the MOTU title may suggest, those volunteers have only so much time to give, and if no-one steps up to help them....  (let alone I don't see any requests to package it when 18.04 was being developed or released)